# Website Thumbnail using Google page speed

Tags: php, thumbnails

I came across an old script that uses *Google PageSpeed Insights* for processing website thumbnails.  I have updated it with the new URL but it does not seem to grab the image.

In this script there are 2 variations, one that uses a base64 image, and the other stores it to your server.  The image is still saved in *myfolder* but it is a broken image.

I would like to know, how can I grab the website thumbnail from Google PageSpeed?

```
<?php
$link = "http://dirtrif.com";
$googlePagespeedData = file_get_contents("https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=$link&screenshot=true");
$googlePagespeedData = json_decode($googlePagespeedData, true);
$screenshot = $googlePagespeedData['screenshot']['data'];
$screenshot = str_replace(array('_','-'),array('/','+'),$screenshot); 
$show_link = "<a href='$link'><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,".$screenshot."\" /></a>";
echo $show_link;

//SOLUTION 2

$name = 'test';
$googlePagespeedData = file_get_contents("https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=$link&screenshot=true");
$googlePagespeedData = json_decode($googlePagespeedData, true);

$screenshot = base64_decode($googlePagespeedData['screenshot']['data']);
$data = str_replace('_','/',$googlePagespeedData['screenshot']['data']);
$data = str_replace('-','+',$data);
$decoded = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('myfolder/'.$name.'.jpg',$decoded);
$file_name = "$name.jpg";
?>
```

Comment: abused tools tend to stop working after a while, instead [get a key](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started) then use the API, its the same API as used on the pagespeed site, then consume `$response['lighthouseResult']['uses-responsive-images']['final-screenshot']` which is base64

Comment: didnt even know that was an option, thank you!  add it as an aswer, it's good enough for me =)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just wanted to let you know I have succefully got this working, that was easy =) Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!